# Who do you want [your best man to be] [to be your best man]

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

> Who do you want your best man to be?
>
> Who do you want to be your best man?

If I want to ask the future bridegroom about who he will choose to be his future best man, which one is the correct one to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are possible.

If we look at the possible answers:

> I want Joe to be my best man.
>   I want my best man to be Joe.

This is essentially the same as comparing:

> Joe is my best man.
>
> My best man is Joe.

There are slight differences.  The first sentence is a "about Joe", the second is "about my best man".

There is also the matter of "end weighting", which is the tendency to put longer structures at the end of sentences.  Because of this I would tend to prefer

> Who do you want to be your best man?

It puts the longer phrase "your best man" after the shorter one "to be".